# Solr: Atomic updates not consistently working

Tags: solr, lucene, atomic, solrcloud

I've been using Atomic updates to Solr documents as a means of avoiding completely rebuilding the records when something changes, but it doesn't seem to be consistently working. For example, I POST something like the following on `/solr/myCollection/update`:

```
{ "add": {
   "overwrite" : true,
   "doc" : {
     "subscriptions" : {
       "remove" : [
         "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR"
       ]
     },
     "id" : "messages/NbRkzeqngmLF2D32WdjDmaYzNqMh2VkG"
   }
 },  "add": {
   "overwrite" : true,
   "doc" : {
     "subscriptions" : {
       "remove" : [
         "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR"
       ]
     },
     "id" : "messages/S6AZ602Vz4EAgdcqCZSnkXGEcDKC2puL"
   }
 },  "add": {
   "overwrite" : true,
   "doc" : {
     "subscriptions" : {
       "remove" : [
         "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR"
       ]
     },
     "id" : "messages/OeyOtZApaJglZ3XgU7uq2o49S7GydCzw"
   }
 },  "commit": {

 }}
```

(snippet shortened for StackOverflow, can be hundreds per batch)

I expect it will remove the supplied aliases from the `subscriptions` field, but it's not:

```
{
        "id":"messages/NbRkzeqngmLF2D32WdjDmaYzNqMh2VkG",
        "streamId":"streams/0jbNwQd5g2tqN1vpRRifYGhH97Fz62le",
        "streamLabel":"Welcome Center",
        "sourceId":"sources/DTibywwJ1ZNIm4JXzc8F5gXA5phmcinH",
        "sourceLabel":"general",
        "creator":"aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR",
        "creatorUsername":"mhicks",
        "creatorName":"Matt Hicks",
        "subscriptions":["groups/public",
          "aliases/9Nu0zc3eS7bCnhwP7Bw2WVYkDILC4MZE",
          "aliases/0hN67LeVaeWKniYUv9jT4YPmqottCqRZ",
          "aliases/dugX1k8JQ2RrEiVuxfKV8qBftL3dRtEd",
          "aliases/4Ulkxjdjc3uFBc2828L7JDNQkjiC84vv",
          "aliases/DbByXFl2NCcoKThSA4yGv8pKBM1dWhFp",
          "aliases/JCDTqlyJuFSjBe0tkng1mzet6pL4F55F",
          "aliases/ZWAQCMYoycEHgZgkAJ6bxo4v8yX87jYJ",
          "aliases/CDCZDosfX4R3DAq0JJNZA40Q0xHiCRVu",
          "aliases/2ziDmuiVkGNGvE0njc4SwWraRJNJRVHb",
          "aliases/1xNazeGAv20I9MIbeSXwzwVQCTlOh2zZ",
          "aliases/CRcvnOA1fJJzFms4QqyPJcVAvAqmOKLb",
          "aliases/qFe3qWuasRiPAA41y5MK4ub1HbgSihb1",
          "aliases/LlKfoB815ztAhW1DH6XtZEXZ9Un3l48u",
          "aliases/OZhEhBH93wsXINety2w0xFg4hnwQl4yI",
          "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR",
          "aliases/q8blp7SopFFE7OKhvhOsU1h7abXQPVpx",
          "aliases/UAR27PGeXUzfhcRgNBWwQGHzkc7Lg0MQ",
          "aliases/9kHPOtdiausgfitQeiO2NfeuaTesXqE5",
          "aliases/8jryJ5wn6WTBWfYCVQcKelgiCwAfjVBZ",
          "aliases/5yz9Br4m4ODSx2ydklJN5xKF7zMCosOh",
          "aliases/NLjQvsm2hzLcyWSs67FsvYcylCOjhZSj",
          "aliases/rItMpsP5jNnFXAHj33ybe0ZJ8aVe1AYk",
          "aliases/lsCmZCkm2GJ8IeqwLCOrZTKQcsc7pf1a",
          "aliases/9BgLlfn3DYmMtYU4B7VIyo54p7xPbOv9",
          "aliases/ChNDsmWrgsDPs0XjuDEbt036EKryZoSi",
          "aliases/WuFOXLN5bPRzanWlWADjIiO1RrIeJ5GO",
          "aliases/KBs2oB9GBzHvRc24eH7u55o7JxpZqPz9",
          "aliases/zY7Je82JF12ZtF0otSjcPwItVgZqZB9g",
          "aliases/ncDj6orc8c7Uhjuohuy2HcvaP1D07Yx5",
          "aliases/vfSQiOMUhmKsLZN97HHaZQnsjY9KAIuK",
          "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR",
          "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR",
          "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR",
          "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR",
          "aliases/nBro7MgwqMeMHFm2Z1sSYzVqL21DxJtR"],
        "created":1565453073618,
        "modified":1565453073618,
        "_version_":1642305728917012480}
```

Even worse, I'm using `add-distinct` when I add the aliases, but as you can see from the snippet above, it's adding a new entry each time.

The call returns successfully without errors, but it's obviously not doing what I'm expecting. It seems to work some of the time though and I can't seem to determine rhyme or reason for why.  To be clear, it's consistently not working for this specific scenario.

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm running SolrCloud on this dev instance on 8.0.0.

Comment: What is the type of the `subscriptions` field? First guess is that it's a text field and since it's being processed, the value to be removed can't be found as a single token. See if it works better with `string` as the type (I'm not sure if this is a limitation, but it's the first thing I'd try).

Comment: @MatsLindh, `subscriptions` is a multi-valued `string` field already